# Почему у меня не отображается phpinfo в мною созданной папке (Linux)

Tags: php, linux, apache2

1. Путь папки: `/home/user/project/index.php`
   В index.php:

```html
<?php
phpinfo();
```

2)Права у папки: `rwxr-xr-x`
Права у файла: `-rw-r--r--`

3)Указываю путь в `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

```
ls => 000-default.conf
```

Путь: `/home/user/project`

4. Добавляю папку в конфиг `apache2.conf`

ps.Естественно я не забываю делать service apache2 restart
после проделанных действий, и я получаю `Forbiden 403`.